# Importing all exports in a module NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to access all exports of a module without having to say `module.` before the export.

Let's say that I have a module:

```
// mymod.js
module.exports.foo = function() {
    console.log("foo!");
}
module.exports.bar = "bar!";
```

And a main file:

```
// main.js
var mymod = require("./mymod.js");
mymod.foo();
```

Is there a way to call `foo()` without needing to say `mymod.` before? This can be achieved in python by saying `import module as *`.
What is the NodeJS equivalent to this?

Comment: I would recommend `require("./mymod") instead of `require("./mymod.js")`, as they all do the same thing, but less typing.

Answer (score 18):

In ES6 you can import modules in the following ways

```
import moduleName from "path/to/module"; // import default export from the file as moduleName object, moduleName can be anything
import { exportMemberName1, exportMemberName2, ... } from "path/to/module"; // destructured import, it will destructure import and can access the export module without prefixing anything
import * as moduleName from "path/to/module"; // import everything exported from the file as moduleName object, you can access every export members from that object, moduleName can be anything
```

These are the only methods provided by ES6 to import module (you can also use  `require`).

If you have to import 100s of modules best ways is third method, import everything as an object and destructure on the go, I meant if you have lots of functions or methods, destructure what you want in that function in side that function, eg.

```
import * as moduleName from "path/to/file";

function function1(){
    const { exportMember1, exportMember2 } = module;
}

function function2(){
    const { exportMember1, exportMember5, exportMember7 } = module;
}
```

Comment: This part is wrong I think: 

`import moduleName from "path/to/module"; // import everything exported from the file as moduleName object, you can access every export members from that object, moduleName can be anything`
...
The `import module from '...'` imports the default export not all exports. `import * as all` imports all exports.

Comment: Actually not wrong, you can but you don't have to `import * as module from "..."`, default import will also import everything from that file, for eg, you can check packages like react, it doesn't have default export, but we can do `import React from "react"` same goes for custom modules.

Comment: It's using default... https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/index.js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong thankyou very much for correcting and arguing with me, , in my thought somewhere I had an experience of using default import to import all, i tried that again and it's not working, I have corrected the answer

Answer (score 4):

> I want to be able to access all exports of a module without having to
>   say module. before the export.

Use the shorthand:

```
exports.myVar = myVar
exports.foo = () => {}
```

Or use an Object:

```
module.exports = {
  foo,
  myVar
}
```

---

```
// main.js
var mymod = require("./mymod.js");
mymod.foo();
```

> Is there a way to call foo() without needing to say mymod. before?
>   This can be achieved in python by saying import module as *. What is
>   the NodeJS equivalent to this?

Use destructuring:

`const { foo } = require("./mymod.js")`

> lets say that I have 100 exports in a file. Do I need to put commas
>   after every import inside the { }? There must be a better way to do
>   this

If you have 100 exports why would you want to import them all globally as their own functions? `myMod.func` is better for clarity.

A hacky workaround might be to do `const myMod = require('myMod')` then map it putting the functions on the global object. Or put them on the global from the start instead of exporting it.

Comment: explanation please.  `() => {}` is the most cryptic thing Ive seen in years

Answer (score 3):

You can use ES6 destructuring:

```
var { foo } = require("./mymod.js");
foo();
```

Comment: lets say that I have 100 exports in a file. Do I need to put commas after every import inside the { }? There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: If you have 100 exports in a file and want to call all of them maybe the issue is of another nature. You could do something like `Object.values(mymod).forEach(f => f())`.

Comment: @MattX If you provide a more specific use case you'll get better answers.

Comment: I doubt Matt meant calling each of them one after the other. I guess he meant using a bunch of the imported functions and that it would be cumbersome to use dot notation for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I have a situation where a I have a tiny-but-not-that-tiny generic utilities that is used along a couple of modules (all it's functions are used), in which there is a decent amount of modules already loaded. This functions are obviously named in a way you know there are a part of a generic utilities modules, so the "module.function" it's redundant, does not improve the readeability of the code. So, I prefered to mimick the "import * from module" of Python. Note that this is the first time I come across this situation, therefore, IMO, this mechanism, in almost every case, is not a good practice at all. The only way to do that, is iterating over the exports of the module, and adding the functions to the global object. I made a function to make the intention clear.

```
const importAll = () => {
  return {
    mod: null,
    from(modName) {
      this.mod = require(modName);
      Object.keys(this.mod)
            .forEach(exportedElementId => global[exportedElementId] = this.mod[exportedElementId]);
    }
  }
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
importAll().from('module-name');
```

Note that this only works if the module exports an object. Wont work if the module exports, for example, an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, which may be a bit cleaner and more convenient in some cases: method `importAll()` is implemented **inside** export-heavy module, so it might be called immediately after `require()`, making this call very brief.

This works really well for large modules stuffed with simple standard functions and constants that are used across multiple projects.

Example:

```
// module.js
'use strict';
function func1() { return '4'; };
function func2() { return 2; };
function importAll() { delete this.importAll; Object.assign(global, this); };
module.exports = { func1, func2, importAll };
```

Then, in the main app, module can be unwrapped as follows:

```
// app.js
'use strict';
require('./module').importAll();
console.log("result: '%d'", func1() + func2());
```

There are few caveats though:

- since properties/methods are added to `global` object, those might override some existing properties/methods, so be careful with naming.
- those properties/methods will become available EVERYWHERE: in all modules, sub-modules, etc, so no need to call `require()` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in NodeJS:

```
import * as lib from 'somewhere...'
Object.assign(global, lib)
```